# ggplot - how to modify just one part of the grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a polar graph such as this:

```
library(geomtextpath)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Temperature = c(4.4, 4.6, 6.3, 8.7, 11.6, 14.1, 15.9, 15.5, 13.1, 9.7, 6.7, 4.3),
                 Month = factor(month.name, month.name),
                 MonthRad = seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 12))

rad2deg <- function(rad) {(rad * 180) / (pi)}

ggplot(df, aes(MonthRad, Temperature)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = 0), shape = 4, size = 3, stroke = 1.5) +
  geom_textpath(aes(x = seq(min(MonthRad), max(MonthRad), length.out = 13)[-13] + (2*pi/12)/2, label = Month), y = max(df$Temperature),
                vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$MonthRad), max(df$MonthRad), length.out = 13)[-13],
                     labels = seq(min(df$MonthRad), max(df$MonthRad), length.out = 13)[-13] %>% 
                       rad2deg() %>% 
                       round(0) %>% 
                       paste0("°"),
                     minor_breaks = c(0, max(df$MonthRad)/4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, max(df$Temperature))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, 
                                   vjust = -.5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "darkgrey", 
                                          linetype = "dashed"),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "black"),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(color = "black",
                                          arrow = arrow(angle = 25,
                                                        length = unit(0.02, "native"),
                                                        type = "closed")),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) + 
  coord_curvedpolar()
```

It produces the following image:

[image]

The grey dashed lines are created with `panel.grid.major.x`, and it is in turn set by the breaks in `scale_x_continuous`.

I would like to have the image so that the part of the gridline between the month names is a solid black line. The output should be like in this image below made in paint. I intentionally made the lines that I am referring to very thick so that it's understandable what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to draw the lines using `geom_segment()` and sending new data - i.e. don't map against the original dataset.  Since your months are centered on the `x` axis, to get the location of the "in-between" locations, you  should convert the precise location in degrees (0, 30, 60, etc).

```
# the "in-between" values
newx <- seq(0,330, length.out=12)*(pi/180)
```

I played around to find that you can draw segments of length 2 and it seems to place them properly.  The segments start from `max(df$Temperature)` and extend by 2 units.  Note that we're not actually mapping the aesthetics to a dataframe here - I'm just supply a vector of values.  This works as long as the vector you supply is the same length as the original dataset.  If we wanted to draw anything other than 12 lines, you would have to supply a new dataframe to the `data=` argument.

```
p + geom_segment(
  xend=newx, x=newx,
  y=max(df$Temperature), yend=max(df$Temperature)+2,
  linewidth=1
)
```

[image]